# OnLongPress only touch is not moving

Tags: android, events, ontouchlistener

I got a view in android which I want to accept onLongPress actions.

I've got a OnTouch method which handles stuff when moving around across the screen. But when long pressing without moving the finger, the OnLongPress method should be called.

My effort so far is that I got the onTouch events working. But now, when swiping around the view, the onLongPress method gets called, because logically, I am long pressing the screen.

I just want the onLongPress work when the finger is held still on the screen without moving, is there a way how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should cancel the long press. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#cancelLongPress()):

> public void **cancelLongPress**()
>
> Cancels a pending long press. Your subclass can
>   use this if you want the context menu to come up if the user presses
>   and holds at the same place, but you don't want it to come up if they
>   press and then move around enough to cause scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downX = event.getX();
            downTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            return true;                

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upX = event.getX();
            upTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;
            float deltaTime = upTime - downTime;

            if((deltaX < UNACCEPTABLE_MOVE_DISTANCE) && (deltaTime > MINIMUM_TIME))
                //REPORT LONG PRESS WITH INTERFACE
            else
                //REPORT SOMETHING ELSE
            return true;
        default:
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Therefore the user has to release his finger from the screen, I would prefer the way OnLongPress works. The user doesn't have to lift his finger from the screen for OnLongPress to work, but thanks for Your idea